# Get the path of a jsonata match

Tags: jsonata

I'm using jsonata to query a json file that I have. I have a query that returns an array of results with the value from each match. What I also want to know is what is the exact path to my match.

Example:
Suppose I had the following JSON

```
    "files": [
        {
           "name": "file_1",
           "type": "txt"
        },
        {
           "name": "file_2",
           "type": "csv"
        },
        {
           "name": "file_3",
           "type": "txt"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I had the following query:

```
files[type="txt"].name
```

I would like to know both the value of my query results and the path of all hits. E.g:

```
[
    {value: "file_1", path: "files[0].name"},
    {value: "file_3", path: "files[2].name"}
]
```

Is this something that is possible?

Comment: Given the current dataset, will the index value suffice?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think JSONata has such feature. But there could be another way to achieve what you are looking for.

If you are interested in the index value, there is a built-in operator is JSONata - [Positonal Variable Binding operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#-positional-variable-binding).

And if you're interested in knowing the parent of a given search, you could use the [Parent operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#-parent).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [practical example](https://try.jsonata.org/F_kfXPTea) that builds on @anindya-dey's answer. Maybe it's all you need, maybe not.

### Input json

```json
{
      "files": [
        {
           "name": "file_1",
           "type": "txt"
        },
        {
           "name": "file_2",
           "type": "csv"
        },
        {
           "name": "file_3",
           "type": "txt"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Jsonata expression

```
files#$i[type="txt"].{
  'value': name,
  'path': 'files[' & $i & '].name'
}
```

### Result

```
[
  {
    "value": "file_1",
    "path": "files[0].name"
  },
  {
    "value": "file_3",
    "path": "files[2].name"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful thank you very much. This works perfectly for me